# How to get entries from the .get() function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having problems with everything about this, it's supposed to be a dictionary and a translator, but I gave up on the translator part. Right now, the program cannot get any entries from the .get() function.

```
    from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import json
from difflib import get_close_matches
from googletrans import Translator
#LIBs are done#
root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x500')
root.configure(background = '#71baff')
#Window Created#
data = json.load(open('data.json'))
translator = Translator()
#Dictionary data has been read#

#Variables attened#


#BACKEND ENDED#


#FRONTEND#

welcome = tk.Label(root, text = 'Welcome to the Dictionary & Translator App', bg = '#71baff', fg = '#ffffff')
welcome.pack()
emptylab = tk.Label(root, bg = '#71baff')
emptylab.pack()
defq = tk.Label(root, text = 'Enter the word : ', bg = '#71baff', fg = '#ffffff')
defq.pack()
defentry = tk.Entry(root, bg = '#71baff', fg = '#ffffff')
defentry.pack()
defin = defentry.get()
def getMeaning(w):        
    defin = defentry.get()
        
    if w in data:
        return data[w]
    elif w.title() in data:
        return data[w.title]
    elif len(get_close_matches(w, data.keys())) > 0:
        return data[get_close_matches(w, data.keys()) [0]]
    else :
        return 'The word does not exist'

emptylab = tk.Label(root, bg = '#71baff')
emptylab.pack()
defbutton = tk.Button(root, text = 'Get Definition!', bg = '#71baff', fg = '#71baff', command = getMeaning(defin))
defbutton.pack()
output = getMeaning(defin)
outputlabel = tk.Label(root, bg = '#71baff', fg = '#ffffff', text = output)#need to add text after the functions for the output are done#
outputlabel.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what problem you are having? Have you done any debugging? Do you get an error when you run this? What happens?

Comment: Move the function `getMeaning(w):` above `welcome` and it might fix the issue, BTW what is the error? why cant you use `get()` mention it in your code

Comment: there is no error but there is an issue. The issue is that when the program is launched no matter what you enter to the entry box the value of output is always empty

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `defin` is what you expect? Have you verified that `w.title()` is what you expect? What about the computation of `len(get_close_matches(w, data.keys()))`?  `data.keys()`? You should be checking all of the values used in your if statement to validate your assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event programming is kind of tricky. You shouldn't return data from an event function as when it is set as a command the Button() object has no idea what to do with it. I saw that you tried to program what to do with it, but it would be much more complicated. It is best to try not to pass variables in your command although it can be done when needed. This of course is not finished that is your job hopefully it will get your further along.

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import json
from difflib import get_close_matches


def getMeaning():
    defin = defentry.get()
    w = defin
    if w in data:
        outputlabel.configure(text=data[w])
    elif w.title() in data:
        outputlabel.configure(text=data[w.title])
    elif len(get_close_matches(w, data.keys())) > 0:
        outputlabel.configure(text=data[get_close_matches(w, data.keys())[0]])
    else:
        outputlabel.configure(text='The word does not exist')


# LIBs are done#
root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x500')
root.configure(background='#71baff')
# Window Created#
data = json.load(open('data.json'))

# Dictionary data has been read#

# Variables attened#


# BACKEND ENDED#


# FRONTEND#

welcome = tk.Label(root, text='Welcome to the Dictionary & Translator App', bg='#71baff', fg='#ffffff')
welcome.pack()
emptylab = tk.Label(root, bg='#71baff')
emptylab.pack()
defq = tk.Label(root, text='Enter the word : ', bg='#71baff', fg='#ffffff')
defq.pack()
defentry = tk.Entry(root, bg='#71baff', fg='#ffffff')
defentry.pack()
emptylab = tk.Label(root, bg='#71baff')
emptylab.pack()
defbutton = tk.Button(root, text='Get Definition!', bg='#71baff', fg='#71baff', command=getMeaning)
defbutton.pack()
outputlabel = tk.Label(root, bg='#71baff', fg='#ffffff')
outputlabel.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

I got a file error as I do not have the file. If there are any other errors you get let me know in the comments and we can figure them out.

Comment: as I told there is no error that the IDE gives me. But the issue is when I print the output of the getMeaning() to a label it only returns 'The word doesn't exist' even though I didn't enter anything to the entry yet. Also after it returns that I am not able to use the label anymore basically it just stays like that.

Comment: What you code you only adds to the window once. If you want something to update other than that you have to have a callback. Your getMeaning() function is a callback from a button press event in this case. A callback method you may be interested in is after(). You can do something like ```root.after(1000, getMeaning)``` to run that function every second.